# how to get hyperlinks(URL) from Password Protected PDF on iOS 10.2

Tags: ios, pdf, hyperlink, xcode8, ios10.2

I've spent all day trying to get hyperlinks metadata from **password protected PDFs** in my iPad application.The CGPDF* APIs are a true nightmare, and the only piece of information I've found on the net about all this is that I have to look for an "Annots" dictionary, but I just can't find it in my PDFs.

I tried **without password Protected PDF** in my ipad application it **works proper** everything.also password protected PDF hyperlinks works proper below ios 10.2 version.

only the problem is ios 10.2 & above version

Step 1: (Download pdf reader app from below link)

https://github.com/vfr/Reader

Step 2 : (Download my custom pdf from below link)

http://docdro.id/eAtlQ8z

password : 205062PY1el8@JfoZm90gdUCMKTD!NhH5xabrvEzu7kFWq6iRO

while tap on Hyperlink getting below error:

-[ReaderContentPage annotationLinkTarget:] Bad URI '(null)'

Answer (score 1):

Not an issue with iOS-10.2 version.

But, the issue is with your **pdf encryption**.

In this [dropBox Fixed example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5gbgda66308oorz/Reader-master.zip?dl=0), you can redirect to this [link](http://subscriptions.intoday.in/subscriptions/digitalsubscriptions/index.jsp) via browser.

Comment: oh! then how it works proper below ios 10.2 version devices

Comment: post your pdf creation process so that everyone can check